# Nginx as a reverse proxy serving 301's

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have little experience with NGINX. I am trying to use it as a reverse proxy for a few docker containers running node. The goal is all requests will be funneled through NGINX. Based on routes(url path), a certain route domain.com/graphql will then be passed to a different docker container via NGINX. The domain.com/graphql is basically my API endpoint.

The problem I have is all of my Ajax/Relay client requests being made by the JS living on the client are getting passed as a 301 from NGINX

Request:

```
Request URL:http://domain.com/graphql
Request Method:POST
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:192.168.99.100:80
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:185
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 08 Sep 2016 15:14:02 GMT
Location:http://domain.com/graphql/
Server:nginx/1.11.3
Request Headers
view source
accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:620
content-type:application/json
Host:nomralph.com
Origin:http://domain.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://domain.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

Nginx config:

```
   upstream frontend {
                least_conn;
                server frontend:4444 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
                keepalive 64;
        }

       upstream graphql-upstream {
              least_conn;
              server graphql:3000 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
              keepalive 64;
       }

        server {
              listen 80;
              server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
              root  /var/www/public;
              # Handle static files

              location / {
                  proxy_pass            http://frontend;
                  proxy_http_version    1.1;
                  proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                  proxy_set_header      Connection 'upgrade';
                  proxy_set_header      Host $host;
                  proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_set_header      X-NginX-Proxy    true;
                  proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
              }

             location /graphql {
                  proxy_pass graphql-upstream/graphql;
                  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                  proxy_http_version    1.1;
                  proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                  proxy_set_header      Connection 'upgrade';
                  proxy_set_header      Host $host;
                  proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_set_header      X-NginX-Proxy    true;
                  proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
             }


        }
```

How can I change my configuration in NGINX to allow the requests made to domain.com/graphql to behave with the same HTTP status as request's made to domain.com but be passed to my api servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not referencing my NGINX correctly because I was not using a relative path on the front end.

This questions was answered on serverfault.com https://serverfault.com/questions/801897/nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-serving-301s